# How to get count of values in pandas if the values are stored as ";" delimited values in columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, series

I am trying to analyse Stackoverflow Developer Survey 2019. In that, LanguageWorkedWith column values in each row are semi-colan delimited.
df["LanguageWorkedWith "] returns this series object.

```
Respondent
1                          HTML/CSS;Java;JavaScript;Python
2                                      C++;HTML/CSS;Python
3                                                 HTML/CSS
4                                      C;C++;C#;Python;SQL
5              C++;HTML/CSS;Java;JavaScript;Python;SQL;VBA
                               ...                        
88377                        HTML/CSS;JavaScript;Other(s):
88601                                                  NaN
88802                                                  NaN
88816                                                  NaN
88863    Bash/Shell/PowerShell;HTML/CSS;Java;JavaScript...
Name: LanguageWorkedWith, Length: 88883, dtype: object
```

I tried this code:

```
languages = df["LanguageWorkedWith"].str.split(";")
lan_counter = Counter(languages.apply(pd.Series).values.ravel())
```

But this code returns lot of NaN values. How to get the count of values in better way than this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `.str.get_dummies`:

```
df.LanguageWorkedWith.str.get_dummies(';').sum()
```

Another way, which might be more memory efficient is `str.split`:

```
df.LanguageWorkedWith.str.split(';').explode().value_counts()
```

Output:

```
C             1
C#            1
C++           3
HTML/CSS      5
Java          2
JavaScript    3
Other(s):     1
Python        4
SQL           2
VBA           1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: How to get count of unique values if there was a list object in the column?

Comment: Do you mean a list mixed with other strings? You have to work with them separately then.

Comment: No just list of strings.. like I have stored hashtags of a single post as a list object in each row.

Comment: Then just drop `.str.split(';')` in the second approach.